# Publishing copyright with regard to novels and comics

Tags: copyright, legal, authorship, first-time-author, traditional-publishing

I wasn't sure where to post this, but I have a couple of questions about copyright law regarding written and illustrated works.

If I traditionally publish a novel and maintain the copyright, can I adapt that novel into a graphic novel with the intention of traditionally publishing it?

Also, could I adapt the traditionally published novel into a Webtoon and receive revenue from the comic?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This may be well suited for the [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

When you "sell" your novel to a publisher, you are settling the rights to publish that text, in specific language, into a specific market, like English language rights in North America.

Since you retain the copyright of the story, you are free to redevelop that story in new formats -- stage script, screen play, comic book.

Conceptually, a publish might have some interest in restricting these other expressions of the story, but they would have to be spelled out in your contract with the publisher.